# How to Identify "Flash Message" Error displayed on the page

Tags: selenium

[image]I am working on automation testing. In Our application all the Errors messages will be displayed as "Flash Messages" on top of the page, it will be displayed for few seconds. These messages comes after click on 'Next' button or 'Submit' button on the page.

To find that element, it is not possible. because the element path will be displayed only for that moment. We cann't verify.

When that error displayed, i copied the html of the error, the html will be as below:

```
<document>
  <html class="no-js" dir="ltr">
  <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
     <body class="alert-open alert-with-am-fade-and-slide-top">
       <div class="page-wrapper">
          <spinner-overlay>
           <navbar-panel class="ng-scope">
           <div class="container-main">
              <alerts-container class="alert-container">
                <div class="alert ng-scope top am-fade-and-slide-top alert-danger" ng-class="[type ? 'alert-' + type : null]" style="display: block;">
                 <!-- ngIf: dismissable -->
                 <!-- ngIf: content | isArray:false -->
                 <div class="ng-scope" ng-if="content | isArray:false">
                      <strong class="ng-binding" ng-bind="::title">Error[![enter image description here][1]][1]</strong>
                       <span class="ng-binding" ng-bind-html="content"/>
                 </div>
              <!-- end ngIf: content | isArray:false -->
           <!-- ngIf: content | isArray -->
             </div>
             </alerts-container>
              <!-- /page wrapper -->
       </div>
```

Element path will be like as below:

```
html/body/div[1]/alerts-container/div/div
```

Please see the image attached.

Please help me how to verify through Selenium Script, this error is displayed or not.

Thanks
Sarada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that comes to my mind is to use the `browser.executeScript()` function to watch the scope of the target element (use `angular.element().scope()` to get the scope)

once $watch is triggered, you know it is time to check for the presence of your div.

**Update: ** here is an example that shows how to execute a javascript snippet with Selenium webdriver: https://www.mkyong.com/selenium/how-to-execute-javascript-in-selenium-webdriver/

angularJs is a javascript framework, so, in the example above, if you go to a page that has angular, then you can use angular.

```
driver.executeScript('var element = document.querySelector(".page-wrapper .alert-container"); \
   var scope = angular.element(element).scope(); \
   window.MyDivIsShown = false; \ 
   window.MyDivWatch = scope.$watch(content,function(n,o){ \
       window.setTimeout(function(){ \
          if(n) \
            window.MyDivIsShown = !!document.querySelector(".alert-container strong") \
   },100);');
```

This will add a watch to the scope that would set a flag when content changes. that change will either display the strong element under alert-container div or not, and it will be reflected in the flag.
so, next thing you do is to use selenium to perform an action that should display the div, and read the flag:

```
performActionThatshouldDisplayAlert();
driver.sleep(2000); //couple of seconds
var returnValue = driver.executeScript("window.MyDivWatch(); \
    return window.MyDivIsShown;");
expect(returnValue).to.beTruthy();
```

Note a couple of tricks:

- I use a setTimeout, so that the div will have time to show and the digest cycle can complete. you may need to increase the 100 millisecond time interval.
- I clear the scope watch at the end of the test.
- In our test, we need to wait for everything to settle down. based on the language you are using, you may need to do something other than `driver.sleep()` to wait before examining the flag.

I hope it shows you the crux of what can be done. search a bit to see how to run the executeScript in webdriver for the language you are using, how to make it wait for some time, and based on the assertion framework of your test, how to test if the return value is true or false (I am sure you know most if not all of that).

Comment: I am very sorry, i didn't understand your answer completely. can you please explain in detail this.

Comment: My another question here is, whether we can angularjs in selenium webdriver?

Comment: Answer to this is longer than a comment, I will edit the main post